# Data.table() creating a table of a vector between 2 numbers

Tags: r, data.table, montecarlo

I have:

`y = rep(0:200,1)`

`u = runif(201,0,1)`

`f(y) = probability mass function which takes in values of yi`

I would like to write a function which checks for each value of u whether: `f(yi-1) < ui =< f(yi)` and if so prints the value of y.

For e.g: lets say f(y3) < u7 =< f(y4) then the function will return y4 (which = 3 in this case).

I would like to create a table using data.table() however, I am unsure as to how to approach this

This is to help with the method of inversion for monte carlo in which f(y) is discrete.

Comment: So `f(yi-1) < ui =< f(yi)` should be `f(yi-1) < uj =< f(yi)`? Cause you write `y4` and `u7` in example. Monte Carlo is out of scope this question. Use of data.table is questionable at this moment, cause you want to create some vector.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(data.table)
yourFunction <- function(e) {
 return(e)
}

dt <- data.table(y = rep(0:200,1), u = runif(201,0,1))
dt[,y_lag:= shift(y,+1)]

dt[yourFunction(y_lag) < u & u <= yourFunction(y),]
```